# Thin with SSL support and ruby-debug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, thin, ruby-debug

Does anyone know of a way to run the ruby debugger and SSL at the same time with Thin?

I've been using Thin successfully with Rails 3.0.10.

I start it using `rails server --debugger`, and I can debug my code.

Recently, I have also needed to add SSL support to my application, and I'd like to be able to test it locally with a self-signed certificate.

Unfortunately, I have not found a way to start Thin with SSL support when using `rails server`.

I can successfully start Thin with SSL support by using:

```
thin start --ssl --ssl-verify --ssl-key-file ssllocal/server.key
    --ssl-cert-file ssllocal/server.crt
```

However, I have not found a way to activate the debugger using `thin start`.

*So it seems like I have the choice of running the debugger (`rails server`) or SSL (`thin start`), but not both.*

It seems possible to get Webrick to run SSL using `rails server` by modifying the rails/script file ([see  here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/chris_rohr/configuring_webrick_to_use_ssl.html&ei=53sGT9rTBunu0gHZ-P3XBA&usg=AFQjCNHYkTjUJTeA0nbW-ywpIup83F3Fxw&sig2=dzyS_1rESwyY79HLQ_JVKw)).  I experimented with this approach, but I have not had success.  Here's one of the attempts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 3
# gems installed from the root of your application.

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)


# THIS IS NEW:
require "rails/commands/server"
require 'rack'
require 'thin'
module Rails
  class Server
    def default_options
      super.merge({
        :Port        => 3000,
        :environment => (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "development").dup,
        :daemonize   => false,
        :debugger    => false,
        :pid         => File.expand_path("tmp/pids/server.pid"),
        :config      => File.expand_path("config.ru"),
        :SSLEnable   => true
        :ssl => true,
        "ssl-verify" => true,
        "ssl-key-file" => File.expand_path("ssllocal/server.key"),
        "ssl-cert-file" => File.expand_path("ssllocal/server.crt")       
      })
    end
  end
end


require 'rails/commands'
```

Note: for those who might be wondering, I created an 'ssllocal' directory off my root application directory, and that's where I store the ssl keys and certs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try just requiring the debugger yourself in your development environment.

In your Gemfile:

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /^1.9/
  gem "ruby-debug19", :group => :development
else
  gem "ruby-debug", :group => :development
end
```

And within the config block of your config/environments/development.rb:

```
require 'ruby-debug'
Debugger.start
```

This permits you to place the debugger statement anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution - I hacked the Thin TcpServer to load my self-signed SSL certs, only in the development environment. My `script/rails` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 3 gems installed from the root of your application.

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)

# Hack our SSL certs into Thin TcpServer, only in development environment
require 'thin'
module Thin
  module Backends
    TcpServer.class_eval do
      def initialize_with_SSL(host, port)
        if Rails.env.development?
          Rails.logger.info "Loading SSL certs from ./ssl_dev..."
          @ssl = true
          @ssl_options = {
            :private_key_file => File.expand_path("../../ssl_dev/server.key", __FILE__),
            :cert_chain_file  => File.expand_path("../../ssl_dev/server.crt", __FILE__),
            :verify_peer => nil
          }
        end

        initialize_without_SSL(host, port)
      end

      alias_method :initialize_without_SSL, :initialize
      alias_method :initialize, :initialize_with_SSL      
    end
  end
end

# Must load 'rails/commands' after Thin SSL hack
require 'rails/commands'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got it to finally work on production using Thin:

```
rvmsudo thin start -p 443 --ssl --ssl-key-file ssl/server.key --ssl-cert-file ssl/server.crt
```

If you are having issues with your KEY file, make sure you validate the CSR by using a site like:

```
https://ssl-tools.verisign.com
```

If your CSR fails, then the certificate you receive from your signing authority will fail too. 
My site would refuse to load with the SSL certs, only to find out that I abbreviated my State name to "TX" instead of "Texas" while creating my private key. That was the reason it wasn't working all along! SSL certs are a pain in the ass!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully get the debugging working with ssl enabled thin, using the solution suggested by nathan. Though I had to do one small change of deferring initialization of @ssl after the call of initialize_without_ssl (an alias method for the original TcpServer's initialize)

```
require 'thin'
module Thin
  module Backends
    TcpServer.class_eval do
      def initialize_with_SSL(host, port)
        if Rails.env.development?
          Rails.logger.info "Loading SSL certs from ./ssl_dev..."
          @ssl_options = {
            :private_key_file => File.expand_path("../../ssl_dev/server.key", __FILE__),
            :cert_chain_file  => File.expand_path("../../ssl_dev/server.crt", __FILE__),
            :verify_peer => nil
          }
        end

        initialize_without_SSL(host, port)
        # @ssl initialized after calling the original initialize of TcpServer
        @ssl = true if Rails.env.development? 

      end

      alias_method :initialize_without_SSL, :initialize
      alias_method :initialize, :initialize_with_SSL      
    end
  end
end

  alias_method :initialize_without_SSL, :initialize
  alias_method :initialize, :initialize_with_SSL      
end
```

In the above code snippett, @ssl is set to true after calling the original initialize call of Thin::Backend::TcpServer. I had to do this since the TcpServer invokes its parent's initialize (Thin::Backend:Base) that sets the @ssl to nil

```
  #Base initialize method. Thin gem version 1.5.0
  def initialize
    @connections                    = []
    @timeout                        = Server::DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
    @persistent_connection_count    = 0
    @maximum_connections            = Server::DEFAULT_MAXIMUM_CONNECTIONS
    @maximum_persistent_connections = Server::DEFAULT_MAXIMUM_PERSISTENT_CONNECTIONS
    @no_epoll                       = false
    @ssl                            = nil
    @threaded                       = nil
  end
```

As noted in nathan's code block, the whole solution appears to be a hack around. In my opinion, I am fine with the snippet considering  the code is done within the context of env.development and most importantly it allows debugging with ssl enabled.