# Rails and https (ssl) running on linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ssl, https

I've been looking for tutorials how to start SSL on my localhost. But ones that I found was related to using nginx or apache. I'm wondering is it possible to use HTTPS(SSL) on localhost using usual ruby server (like webrick, thin, unicorn)?

Comment: have you seen this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1?view=asciicast? It might help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked [Thin with SSL support and ruby-debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753566/thin-with-ssl-support-and-ruby-debug)

Additionally you will need your own certificate try this page http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20041129143420344 for a step-by-step tutorial for osX