# Enable https in a rails app on a thin server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, thin

I have a rails app running a thin server on heroku. It currently uses http. I would like to use https for bot development and production. Where do I begin to do this.

I have looked at this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/357-adding-ssl) where they show how to use a POW server. I dont want to use a POW server, I want to use a Thin server.

I also looked [here](http://www.buildingwebapps.com/articles/79189-using-ssl-in-rails-applications): But here they assume that you have open ssl insatlled.

I haven't found any place which shows how to run https on a thin server from scratch.

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't know if you need it, but this helped me:

```
  thin start --ssl --ssl-verify --ssl-key-file ssllocal/server.key
--ssl-cert-file ssllocal/server.crt
```

edit path to ssl key and ssl fild. For example my keys were in paypal folder, so command was

```
    thin start --ssl --ssl-verify --ssl-key-file paypal/server.key
--ssl-cert-file paypal/server.crt
```

If you will have problems you can look at this post - [Thin with SSL support and ruby-debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753566/thin-with-ssl-support-and-ruby-debug).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ain't it possible to move this to `development.rb` config file to keep using `rails server` command?

Comment: I ask the same, is there a config file for thin where I can put all those SSL settings in?

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
$ thin start --ssl
```

You will need a separate instance if you want both ssl and non-ssl ports.

Comment: I run `thin start -e production --ssl --ssl-key-file ~/.ssl/<mydomain>.key --ssl-cert-file ~/.ssl/bundle.crt` 
Both my .key file and the .crt file are in place. The server starts fine but I cannot access any of my API endpoints anymore, what more must be done so that I can accesss all of my endpoints but with `https://` prefix.

Comment: For anyone wondering: `thin --ssl` uses a default SSL cert (via `eventmachine`) when the cert file and key file aren't specified. The name on the cert is odd: https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/681 You wouldn't want to use this in production.

Answer (score 8):

You should to use **thin** to do it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install thin
```

And add this line in config/application.rb

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Then run app on thin with command line:

```
$ thin start --ssl
```

Comment: Warning if you're just experimenting: using `force_ssl` will, among other things, enable HTTP Strict Transport Security. So your browser will be told "ONLY use https on this domain." If the domain is `localhost`, that may confuse you later. You can Google how to clear HSTS in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps ..its taken directly from the awesome makandra card...I am pasting the steps below..but do visit the page for better clarity.

Note -
Although, this didn't helped me as I wanted to setup https to check Stripe Google Pay button, but could'nt proceed due to some reasons...I will try to use ngrok to setup https and share my updated learnings.

QUICK UPDATE -
Next day, I tried Ngrok and following the link - https://ngrok.com/download and
https://www.sitepoint.com/use-ngrok-test-local-site/ and I was able to test stripe successfully.

> Create a directory .ssl in your home directory. Go there and create a
> self-signed certificate. It is important to enter localhost.ssl as
> Common Name when asked. This is to make your browser believe the
> certificate is owned by the localhost domain.
>
> Add localhost.ssl to your hosts file
>
> echo "127.0.0.1 localhost.ssl" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts Put the
> attached initializer into config/initializers. It monkey-patches the
> ForceSSL module to work in development and incorporates two custom
> config settings: use_ssl and ssl_port.
>
> In your application.rb, add config.use_ssl = false. (Turn off SSL
> generally.)
>
> In your environments/production.rb add config.use_ssl = true. (Turn on
> SSL in production.)
>
> In your environments/development.rb add config.use_ssl = true and
> config.ssl_port = 3001. (Turn on SSL in development and point your app
> to port 3001.)
>
> Add force_ssl to any controller you need. You may provide :only =>
> :some_action and :except => :some_unsafe_action as options.
>
> Boot thin
>
> thin start -p 3001 --ssl --ssl-key-file ~/.ssl/server.key
> --ssl-cert-file ~/.ssl/server.crt The option -p tells thin to bind to port 3001. To have a http development server running at the same time,
> start it with thin start -p 3000. (To run your application with thin,
> add gem 'thin' to your Gemfile.)
>
> Point your browser to http://localhost:3000. You should be redirected
> to https://localhost:3001/. Do not expose a client certificate if
> asked, cancel that alert. It will just work fine without.

Link to Makandra Card - https://makandracards.com/makandra/15903-using-thin-for-development-with-ssl