# Error message received for rails server when I try to visit https://localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Whenever I execute "rails server" and try to visit `https://localhost:3000`, I get the following error message. Any Idea what's going on?

Thanks!

```
=> Booting WEBrick

=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000

=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

[2014-02-04 14:00:34] INFO WEBrick 1.3.1

[2014-02-04 14:00:34] INFO ruby 2.0.0 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]

[2014-02-04 14:00:34] INFO WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=25445 port=3000

[2014-02-04 14:00:37] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00?\x01\x00\x00?\x03\x03R?8?Rcd?0j?`\\?6?>??f?&-??pB???B\x00\x00J\x00??$?#?'.

[2014-02-04 14:00:37] ERROR bad URI `"^;?\x00?D\x1D??׆?wјH?\x15?.\x10M?\x00\x00J\x00??$?#?'.

[2014-02-04 14:00:37] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x00\x00E\x01\x00\x00A\x03\x00R?8հBo?㦈r?\x19'.
```

Answer (score 11):

You're trying to connect via HTTPS, which is not supported. WEBrick is expecting plain HTTP so it does not know how to parse the encrypted request.

Unless you really need HTTPS in development, just use HTTP. If you need HTTPS, it is possible to do so but will require some configuration changes. For example, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589636/enable-https-in-a-rails-app-on-a-thin-server) question for how to do it with thin.

Comment: do you know how to switch to HTTP? Thanks!

Comment: @user1571767 just open your browser at `http://localhost:3000` instead of `https://localhost:3000`.