# Ruby on rails: force_ssl not redirecting from http to https when using thin start --ssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ssl-certificate, thin

I have been trying to configure my rails project to use SSL (as application wide) with thin (by adding thin gem and placing `config.force_ssl = true` to `application.rb`) but as a result, I have an annoying problem.

When I start my rails server using `rails s` and try to access `http://localhost:3000` it redirects to `https://localhost:3000` which is correct, however it will complain about missing SSL certification..

> SSL connection error
>
> Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a
>   problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client
>   authentication certificate that you don't have.

On the other hand, If I start my application using `thin start --ssl` and try to access `http://localhost:3000` it doesn't redirect to `https://localhost:3000` and complains about this:

> No data received
>
> Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.

but by accessing `https://localhost:3000` it just shows certificate warning but it all works after agreeing to continue.

**So my question is**, How can I make http to https redirection work when using SSL with thin in (development mode)?

Perfect answer would contain possibility to start server normally by using `rails s` while SSL would be enabled application wide and accessing http redirects to https and all works! :)

Thanks in advance, have been searching for hours but cant find an answer.

Comment: Facing the same problem buddy. Any leads on it?

Comment: did you find a solution to this. I am trying this on a Rails4 app.

Answer (score 0):

You should install your own openssl signed certificate.
You can find more information on this [page](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your PC as (localhost) can self sign SSL certificate and your browser can accept it, but i think that browser will not automatically accept certificate with security on that layer. Maybe to try to add your localhost certificate to the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Verify config/environments/development.rb has the following line

> config.force_ssl = true

Refer the post [thin with ssl support and ruby debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753566/thin-with-ssl-support-and-ruby-debug/16377824) and the responses(from nathan and shree) that has more information on this subject:

Answer (score 0):

Use ngrok (https://ngrok.com/). It's free. Installation is easy.

Just start up your server, then in another terminal window run

```
ngrok http 3000
```

ngrok will give you an address that loops back to your dev machine - something like http://randomstringhere.ngrok.io

Put that in your browser and you'll see it redirect to https://randomstringhere.ngrok.io, still routing to your server on port 3000

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simplest solution.

https://makandracards.com/makandra/15903-using-thin-for-development-with-ssl